# I am passing HttpClient header "application/json" but still getting error "header": "Content-Type", "error": "cannot be blank"

Tags: c#, get, dotnet-httpclient

Using `HttpClient.Get` method, I am passing `content-Type = application/json` but still I am getting an error

> "header": "Content-Type","error": "cannot be blank"

in the response body.

I tried this way:

```
restclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

and also like this:

```
restclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

error I got:

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you send Contents in HTTP it means you have body data and there is a header Content-Length that is the byte count of the body data.  So error indicates the body and length isn't consistent.

Comment: Can you format your question, please? It will be easier to read. (Code with code tag for example)     

Please also present some screenshots, if you put a breakpoint there, can you check if the value is present?

Comment: Include _ALL_ of the code relevant to the http call. As is, there isn't enough information.

Comment: @DavidL please refer screenshots I have attached